# FlexSlider v2.4.0 responsive issues (Images not aligning correctly) when i reduce browser window

Tags: flexslider

Example: http://www.internationalflow.com/2016IFT/single.html
Looks fine in a normal web browser window but when i resize the browser window to display mobile phone size the flexslider images are not displaying correctly, They are not aligning up to view one image at a time. Does anyone know how to fix this bug?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please update FlexSlider to the newest version 2.6.1. 
You used Media Queries in flexslider.css, for example:

```
@media(max-width:1024px){
 li.clone {
    width: 275px!important;
}
}
```

Please remove all lines for this element `li.clone` in Media Queries.